# elasticsearch Cluster not rebalancing after adding nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster with 2 nodes,  I added 3 more nodes which joined the cluster.  I am able to send request to them and get results.  however when i check they dont have any documents.  I have a 5 shard index and i was expecting that each node would receive a shard?

[image: 3 new nodes have no documents]

```
{
    cluster_name: "es-poc",
    status: "green",
    timed_out: false,
    number_of_nodes: 5,
    number_of_data_nodes: 5,
    active_primary_shards: 5,
    active_shards: 10,
    relocating_shards: 0,
    initializing_shards: 0,
    unassigned_shards: 0,
    delayed_unassigned_shards: 0,
    number_of_pending_tasks: 0,
    number_of_in_flight_fetch: 0,
    task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis: 0,
    active_shards_percent_as_number: 100
}
```

Comment: I would speculate that rebalancing failed due to some error. In order to figure out what caused it, I would enable verbose logging for one of the newly added nodes, and then tried to force shard allocation by following examples at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/cluster-reroute.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the responses,  the issue was that the versions where not the same on all the nodes,  the existing members had 2.3.4,  while the new members had 2.3.3.

i found this out by doing:

```
POST _cluster/reroute?explain
{
  "commands": [
    {
       "move" :
            {
              "index" : "event4", "shard" : 0,
              "from_node" : "Toad", "to_node" : "Amelia Voght"
            }
        }

  ]
}
```

in the response i saw this in the explain section

```
 {
               "decider": "node_version",
               "decision": "NO",
               "explanation": "target node version [2.3.3] is older than source node version [2.3.4]"
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

Rebalancing depends on several settings.

[Shards Allocation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/shards-allocation.html)

> Regardless of the result of the balancing algorithm, rebalancing might not be allowed due to [forced awareness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/allocation-awareness.html#forced-awareness) or [allocation filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html).